# Get elements by data attribute and part of id in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute

I need to get elements by **data** attribute and part of **id** in **jQuery**.
I have following code.

```
<div class="bridgeSelectedDiv" id="bridgeDiv_13234" onclick="SelectBridgeLine(this);" data-bridgeuid="b2a42066-00e2-4b6e-bdef-397468573b75"></div>
<div class="bridgeSelectedDiv" id="bridgeDiv_13432" onclick="SelectBridgeLine(this);" data-bridgeuid="b2a42066-00e2-4b6e-bdef-397468573b75"></div>
<div class="bridgeSelectedDiv" id="bridgeDiv_45646" onclick="SelectBridgeLine(this);" data-bridgeuid="b2a42066-00e2-4b6e-bdef-397468573b75"></div>

function SelectBridgeLine(element) {
 var bridgeuid = $(element).attr("data-bridgeuid");
 var partofSelectedBridgeLine = $('div[id^="bridgeDiv_"]').data("bridgeuid");
 console.log(partofSelectedBridgeLine);
}
```

But it returns only 1 element not all of them. 
Any clue? Thank you!

Comment: did not understand your question. You are getting data attribute and want to place in all other div with id starting from bridgeDiv_, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs of `.data()`

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.

So whats happening here is it gets the data value for first element only. You need to iterate over them using `.each()` to get for all elements in matched selector:

```
$('div[id^="bridgeDiv_"]').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).data('bridgeuid'))
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vVQ4P/)**

Comment: bridgeSelectedDiv class could be replaced that why I have to use id.

Answer (score 1):

It returns only 1 element because you are doing `onclick="SelectBridgeLine(this);"`, and `this` will always point to current element on which the click handler exists, instead do:

```
$('.bridgeSelectedDiv').click(function(){
   console.log($(this).data('bridgeuid')); //you can use .data()
});
```

or

```
$('div[id^="bridgeDiv_"]').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).data('bridgeuid'));
});
```

Comment: that is what i have thought at first place. It does not work thought. due to `.data()` returning property for first element in matched selector.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('div[id^="bridgeDiv_"]').each(function(){ 
   console.log($(this).data("bridgeuid")); });
```